# Set maximum / minimum limits on figure size - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Parts of my figure in matplotlib do not look good (text overflows / lines are crammed up etc.) when the figure is resized to something very small.

To deal with that I want to set limits on how small a matplotlib figure can be, i.e. disallow  user resize operations if the window of the figure has reached its minimum size.

I've looked into the Figure and rcParams documentation but I have not found a way to do this.

Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Create your `Figure` with `plt.subplots` and then call `set_size_inches`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)  # 7 x 5 inches for example
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want.
I want to set the minimum size of a plot, not directly set its size to something fixed.